# Formula for "cleanliness" or "roundness" of fraction

Tags: fractions, information-theory, rationality-testing

I'm looking for some metric that can score fractions or decimals by how "clean" or "round" they are. Put another way, I want to measure inverse "dissonance". I want to give a high score to numbers like 1, 1/2, 2/3, 1/4, etc., and low scores to 3/13, or $\sqrt{2}$.

One idea I had was to just add the numerator and the denominator of the most simplified form, but I wanted to see if there were other ideas out there. I also looked briefly at entropy in cryptography and data compression.

Huge bonus points if the method could handle numbers close to round fractions. So that for example $2^\frac{7}{12} \approx 3/2$ would get a good score even though it's irrational.

Any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: Why should 2/3 get a better score than 3/13, exactly? You'd have to be clearer about what your qualifications of "roundness" are first.

Comment: I'm flexible with the exact qualifications, I'm more looking for ideas of methods out there. For context, I'm looking at frequencies of musical notes. A perfect fifth is almost exactly 3/2 the frequency of the root, and sounds very nice and clean. A minor third is roughly 6/5 the frequency. It sounds darker, but still nice in many contexts. A minor sixth is 1.587 the frequency of the root, and pretty much just sounds bad. I'm trying to put more concrete measurements around this level of dissonance.